# Angular Conditional Rendering based on Selected Option

Tags: angular

I was following a basic angular tutorial on how to create a drop down menu and have the drop down display an array of elements, but I ran into an issue on how to get the value of each option individually. I am trying to conditionally render a header based on the selected option from the drop down list. My drop down has all three of my terms listed, however all three headers are always showing.

Term:

```
export class Term {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Typescript:

```
import { Term } from './term';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-class-search',
  templateUrl: './class-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./class-search.component.css']
})

export class ClassSearchComponent {

  public terms: Term[] = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Summer 2020'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Fall 2020'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Spring 2021'}
  ];

  public selectedTerm: Term = this.terms[0];
  onSelect(termId) {
    this.selectedTerm = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.terms.length; i++) {
      if (this.terms[i].id === termId) {
        this.selectedTerm = this.terms[i];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div class="ui massive menu">
    <select class="ui simple dropdown term" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
      <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Term</option>
      <option *ngFor="let term of terms">{{term.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div *ngFor="let term of terms">
    <div *ngIf="this.selectedTerm.id === 1">
      <h1 class="whichterm">{{this.term.name}}</h1>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="this.selectedTerm.id === 2">
      <h1 class="whichterm">{{this.term.name}}</h1>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="this.selectedTerm.id === 3">
      <h1 class="whichterm">{{this.term.name}}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: many mistakes here... You should try to follow the Angular tutorial (Tour of hero) first. You're using old-style for loop, not using the `*ngFor` properly inside the option tag, using `this` in the HTML (don't !), and use an useless `*ngFor` at the end of your HTML...

Comment: I honestly just wanted a simple example on how to bind a value from a select to display a header based on the selected value, but I can't find something remotely similar.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most minimalistic example I could come up with:

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<select (change)='changeName($event)'>
  <option *ngFor='let option of options'>{{option}}</option>
</select>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  title = 'not set';
  options = [
    'option 1',
    'option 2',
    'option 3'
  ];
  public changeName( event ) {
    this.title = event.target.value;
  }
}
```

The template explained:

- `{{title}}` binds the title property from the model to your template.
- `*ngFor='let option of options'` shows all options in your template.
- `(change)='changeName($event)'` On a change call the changeName function and give it the event object.

The model explained:

The model is pretty simple. It has a title property, a list of options and a function that modifies the title property.

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x3bcdq